# Is not assignable to Activity

Tags: java, android-studio

MusicAdapter Class

```
public class MusicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.MusicVH> {
    List<Musiv> musicList;
    private Context context;

    public MusicAdapter(List<Musiv> musicList) {
        this.musicList = musicList;
    }
    public MusicAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public MusicAdapter( ) {

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MusicVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nice_artist, viewGroup, false);

        return new MusicVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MusicVH musicVH, final int i) {
        Musiv music = musicList.get(i);
        musicVH.albumImage.setImageResource(music.getAlbunImgeId());
        musicVH.artist.setText(music.getArtist());
        musicVH.description.setText(music.getMusic());
        musicVH.artistCard.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                musicList.remove(i);
                notifyItemRemoved(i);
                notifyItemChanged(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
        musicVH.artistCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(musicVH.itemView.getContext(), Description.class);
            intent.putExtra("Name",musicVH.artist.getText());
            intent.putExtra("Description",musicVH.description.getText());
//                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//                int id = musicVH.albumImage.getId();
//                bundle.putInt("image", id);
//                intent.putExtras(bundle);
            //intent.putExtra("Image", musicVH.albumImage.getId());
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return musicList.size();
    }


    class MusicVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView albumImage;
        private TextView artist;
        private TextView description;
        private CardView artistCard;

        public MusicVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            albumImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumImage);
            artist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistName);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.artistDescription);
            artistCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.musicCard);

        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.paulr.adapterlessonsumsungtest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<!--Ошибка ниже-->
        <activity android:name=".MusicAdapter" />
        <activity android:name=".Description"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш класс MusicAdapter это не активность, он расширяет RecyclerView.Adapter, а не Activity. Не нужно его добавлять в манифест. Удалите строку

```
<activity android:name=".MusicAdapter" />
```